# Trying to upgrade recaptch from v1 to v2 on Joomla 2.5 site

Tags: joomla2.5, recaptcha

I've inherited maintenance for a club site which uses reCaptcha v1 on a Joomal 2.5 (I'm also trying to upgrade to Joomla 3.x, but that is a separate issue).  I'm very mucha a Joomla newbie, so be gentle.

I got an email stating

> You are receiving this email because you are registered as a website administrator using reCAPTCHA, and your website is still using reCAPTCHA v1, which will be turned off on March 31, 2018.

I clicked the Developer guide in the link, and applied and received new keys.  I have installed them into a subdomain test site.  Before I overwrote the old keys, the captcha was working correctly.  Now it is not, displaying only *captcha.

The google instructions also tell me to perform the following:

> Paste this snippet before the closing  tag on your HTML template:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

> Paste this snippet at the end of the  where you want the reCAPTCHA widget to appear:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdFhzUUAAAAAPmsD-junpPMr7AUh_TbI-lmx4PX"></div>}
```

I do not have a file called template.html  and I am uncertain what "form" it is that I should paste the 2nd snippet.

Kindly help!

Comment: Buehler?  Anybody?  If I can't find help here nor at Google Groups:reCaptcha, where else can I look?

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't found a solution, I suggest that you try a fix/patch I prepared for a couple clients of mine that had the same issue. Basically, I have modified the code of the standard captcha/recaptcha plugin so it can support reCAPTCHA v2 keys (by default Joomla 2.5 supports only v1). I have also written down detailed instructions on how to call this plugin from 3rd party extensions, which may be necessary if you have at least one component that's calling the default captcha plugin. Here is the URL:

http://www.tabulizer.com/index.php/support-menu/tabulizer-tips/161-how-to-enable-recaptcha-v2-in-joomla-2-5

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this fix and I wrote it because I could not find a working solution elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I have 2 suggestions of where to start.

Recent versions of Joomla have built-in support for reCaptcha. You enable it from System > Global Configuration > Site Settings > Default Captcha.

Settings and your keys are then configured in Extensions > Plugins > Captcha - ReCaptcha, and remember to enable the plugin when you are finished.

It's also possible that the reCaptcha on your site might be coming from a form extension. If the above doesn't solve your problem, what form extension are you using?